# Как установить Я.Онлайн на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Как установить Я.Онлайн на Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас Ubuntu Lucid или Maverick, то последовательность действий следующая.

Получить права суперпользователя:

```
$ sudo -i
```

Выполнить скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "deb http://repo.yandex.ru/ubuntu lucid main non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install yandex-archive-keyring
apt-get -y --force-yes install yachat
```